# How to continue loop when the file is not found

Tags: python

I am trying to print the list of files in the date range set by the user.

This is my sample files: Note that there is no "2015-01-01" in the file

[image]

If I input range from `2015-01-02` to `2015-01-05` it will print the list if files. But if I input from `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-05` it will result in an error:

```
OSError: (2, 'No such file or directory', '\\2015-01-01')
```

Is it possible to have try-except-pass or continue so that my loop will still continue and prints `2015-01-02` to `2015-01-05`. And just deny the file not found.

This is my current code:

```
FileNameList = []
date = start_date
while date <= end_date:
    folder_name = date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    data_folder = path.join(pathDir, folder_name)
    #print data_folder  

    for filefolder in os.listdir(data_folder):      
        filefolder = data_folder + "\\" + filefolder

    FileNameList.append(filefolder)

    date += delta_one_day

for filefolder in FileNameList:
    for file in os.listdir(filefolder):
        if ".txt" in file:
            filename = filefolder + "\\" + file 
            print filename
```

Comment: Is the `FileNameList.append` statement supposed to be in the first for loop? The `filefolder` variable used by your `for` loop is overwritten on each iteration of the `for` loop, and then the variable `filefolder` is appended to `FilenameList` only after the entire `for` loop finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround the `os.listdir` call with a  try except:

```
try:
    for filefolder in os.listdir(data_folder):      
        filefolder = data_folder + "\\" + filefolder
except OSError:
    pass
```

Comment: This won't finish the `for` loop if the OSError occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You could try/except the loop, but a better solution might be to only append existing directories to your list in the first place:

```python
# your code and while loop here

if os.path.isdir(data_folder):
    for filefolder in os.listdir(data_folder):      
        filefolder = data_folder + "\\" + filefolder

    if os.path.isdir(filefolder):
        FileNameList.append(filefolder)
```

Putting a `for` loop inside a try/except block can get a little messy, since you won't be able to continue the loop where you left off in the case that an exception occurs. But if you do want to stick with the [EAFP strategy](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```python
for filefolder in FileNameList:
    try:
        files = os.listdir(filefolder)
    except OSError:
        # You could log/print a warning here if you need.
        continue
    for file in files:
        if ".txt" in file:
            filename = filefolder + "\\" + file 
            print filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You gave the answer yourself.

```
try:
    #handles the file
except OSError:
    pass # or log it if needed.
```

Comment: ``pass`` should be replaced with ``continue``

Comment: if I use "pass" there is no output result but if I use "continue" the application will stuck and hang.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **continue statement** :

The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning of the while loop. The continue statement rejects all the remaining statements in the current iteration of the loop and moves the control back to the top of the loop.

The continue statement can be used in both while and for loops.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

for letter in 'Python':     # First Example
   if letter == 'h':
      continue
   print 'Current Letter :', letter

var = 10                    # Second Example
while var > 0:              
   var = var -1
   if var == 5:
      continue
   print 'Current variable value :', var
print "Good bye!"
```

This will produce following result:

```
Current Letter : P
Current Letter : y
Current Letter : t
Current Letter : o
Current Letter : n
Current variable value : 10
Current variable value : 9
Current variable value : 8
Current variable value : 7
Current variable value : 6
Current variable value : 4
Current variable value : 3
Current variable value : 2
Current variable value : 1
Good bye!
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example where we check that the directory exists before progressing with the for loop.
It may be considered more 'pythonic' to use a try, except block, however I believe that in this instance a simple check is cleaner (just my opinion).

```
for filefolder in FileNameList:
    # CHECK THAT THE DIRECTORY EXISTS HERE
    if not os.path.isdir(filefolder):
        continue # this instruction will immediately jump to the next for loop iteration, effectively skipping the current iteration.
    for file in os.listdir(filefolder):
        if ".txt" in file:
            filename = filefolder + "\\" + file 
            print filename
```

Comment: The check needs to be `os.path.isdir` instead of `os.path.exists`, since `os.listdir` will throw `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:` if it is passed a path to a file.