# check directory existence so for loop keeps running

Tags: python, exception, directory, global-variables, glob

I was wondering how I can check if my path exists in a global for loop.  I was thinking of embedding an if statement within my for looop but I realized that this doesn't work.  I need a check before my loop.  But that doesn't make sense because how do I get it to loop through the path if the "if statement" is before the for loop?

```
for path in glob.glob("/Users/Downloads/FATES/*network5_01"):                                                                                                                                              
  if not os.path.exists(path):
    raise Exception("No results found from glob expression", path)
```

This doesn't work unfortunately.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238504/how-to-continue-loop-when-the-file-is-not-found) but it wasn't very helpful.

I want the for loop (if a directory doesn't exist), for it to continue, but raise an exception as to which directory didn't exist.

Comment: You're trying to search all subdirectories for files?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is going to get a list of paths that match the given glob, and then immediately iterate over that list and throw an Exception if any of them disappear during the iteration.

This exception will only get thrown *if a file is deleted between when the `glob` is expanded and when the existence of the path is checked*.

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think what you're trying to do is get a list of files that exist at the start of the program, and then raise an Exception when any of those disappear. That you can do like this:

```
import time                                                                                                                                                                                             

# Get the list at program start.
original_list = glob.glob("/Users/kjoyner/src/*") 

while True: 
    time.sleep(1) # Do work here.
    new_list = glob.glob("/Users/kjoyner/src/*") 
    for file in original_list: 
        if file not in new_list: 
            raise Exception("Missing file: {0}".format(file))
```

When I delete a file in that directory in another window, I see:

```
Exception: Missing file: /Users/kjoyner/src/sacrificial
```

Note that if someone *adds* a file after the program starts, and then deletes it, then this code won't catch that because the file wouldn't be in `original_list`. If you wanted to catch this then you would want to use sets instead of lists, and update `original_list` (which you would want to rename) on each loop to be the union of `original_list` and `new_list`.

Note also that this is not recursive. If someone deletes a subdirectory of the directory you're in, no Exception will be thrown because it was not in `original_list` either.